Sentry Logging python integration - which handler?
So if there are 2 handlers to a logger say
     ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
            ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            ch.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(message)s'))  # Logs are pre-formatted as JSON strings
    
            # File handler for custom human-readable output
            fh = logging.FileHandler(os.environ["LOG_FILE_LOCATION"])
            fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
            fh.setFormatter(CustomFileFormatter())
    
            logger.addHandler(ch)
            logger.addHandler(fh)

which handler will be used by sentry to display an error message ?
Also, if i want to custom format the output thats sent to sentry what should i do ?
If a sample message in sentry is like this,
{"event": "Error event", "logger": "A.a1", "level": "error", "environment": "staging",  "image_name": "X", "target_module": "Y", "filename": "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/structlog/stdlib.py", "lineno": 247, "function": "_proxy_to_logger", "timestamp": "2024-07-22T06:58:00.499028Z"}

what can I do to have a sentry record with message = event and all other key/value pairs as tags and values to them

How do you integrate sentry into your code?

sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(
level=logging.INFO,  # Capture info and above as breadcrumbs
event_level=logging.ERROR  # Send errors as events
)

Neither. Sentry's LoggingIntegration itself is effectively a third handler which does its own thing. It'll take messages passing through the logging system, filter them by log level based on the configuration of Sentry's LoggingIntegration and the usual logging system configuration. log levels applied to specific loggers will take priority over the configuration of Sentry's LoggingIntegration.
You'd have to check whether it has the same controls a regular log handler has to see if it provides format controls. It may accept parameters that can help set these, but it's not immediately evident from a quick skim of the documentation.
Depending on which framework(s) you're using, you might need to look at the Sentry documentation on how to correctly integrate with them. By default, Sentry logging integration ignores the logs from some libraries or frameworks, and you may need to manually enable their inclusion. The integration examples for various frameworks show you how to enable all the usually needed loggers.
